# Multiple Oracle Databases Connection from Python with following syntax, without relying on any client side files

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, ldap

I have 2 JDBC connection strings, with the following syntax to connect to an Oracle databases over an LDAP connection.

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://acmeldap.acme.com:3000/dmart,cn=OracleContext,dc=acme,dc=com

jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://acmeldap.acme.com:3000/smart,cn=OracleContext,dc=acme,dc=com
```

Along with a unique Username and Password for each database.

How can I connect to above 2 Oracle databases at simultaneously to run the SQL query and read data into the Pandas table using python program.

Have tried the solutions mentioned in the question [cx_Oracle LDAP Connection String syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37933090/cx-oracle-ldap-connection-string-syntax) but that does not work for multiple databases connectivity at same time.

I tried the cx_Oracle and jaydebeapi libraries to connect but unable to connect.

Comment: What do you mean with simultaneously? What about doing so:
- open connection 1 -> run your query -> close connection 1
- open connection 2 -> run your query -> close connection 2

Comment: Yeah, that is also fine for me, but when looked for the solutions, I could see the Existing solutions depends on the few config files on client computer, But, during the execution of program I can't change the config files on the client system. hence, I am looking for way to connect oracle Database over LDAP without using any config files.

Comment: Not currently possible.  You'll need to configure those config files.